# Is there a Malach for Am Yisrael?

Tags: am-yisrael-jewish-nation, malach-angel

I had a very bizarre dream where at the end I was in a room singing then having a heated discussion with someone who claimed to be the malach of 'Am Yisrael'. Is there such a thing as a Malach for Am Yisrael?

Comment: Hi M.he and welcome to mi.yodeya! This is an interesting question, but is probably too localized to fit the guidelines of the site. You might find some very informative information in these and questions like them: [Mal'achim](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/888/3), [Mal'achim](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18789/3), [Dreams](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10502/3), [Dreams](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26414/3)

Comment: But, then again it might be fine! See [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for more than you ever wanted to know about how subjective questions are recommendably formulated and treated.

Comment: The questions of whether malachim *ever* appear in dreams, or whether Am Yisrael has a malach, are questions which seem completely appropriate to this site. However, if the OP is asking for an interpretation of his own dream, then that probably isn't.

Comment: There's no question in this question post, but the title has two questions very different from each other. I'm editing one of those out; you can ask it separately if you like.

Comment: No, see pirkei derabbi eliezer perek 24. Other nations have their malachim, we have Hashem.

Comment: @joshwaxman See http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9884#showrashi=true הִנֵּה אָנֹכִי שֹׁלֵחַ מַלְאָךְ לְפָנֶיךָ לִשְׁמָרְךָ בַּדָּרֶךְ וְלַהֲבִיאֲךָ אֶל הַמָּקוֹם אֲשֶׁר הֲכִנֹתִי:

Comment: yes, that is a pasuk. or are you referring to the Rashi? What of it, that you believe says that there is an Sar/Malach of Am Yisrael?

Comment: @joshwaxman Thank you. Please explain how you understand the use of the word malach in the possuk and how does it differ from the concept of a Sar/Malach of Am Yisrael?

Comment: First some meforshim say it it moshe. Others might say it is the pillar, or the Shechina. Let us say it is a malach, a messenger of Hashem sent for a specific task. Of course Hashem sends messengers, just as Hashem sent messengers to Avraham. Does that make the three angels the angels of Avraham? A sar is an angel appointed permanently as the heavenly representative of that nation. The idea of a sar for am yisrael will IMHO swiftly lead to idolatry, which is I think why chazal were so against it and where I also fear the questioner may be headed.

Answer (score 10):

Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer, [perek 24](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%9B%D7%93), makes it clear that while other nations get their own angel, Israel gets Hashem himself.

> ר' שמעון אומר קרא הקב"ה לשבעים מלאכים המסובבים כסא כבודו ואמ' להם באו ונבלבל את לשונם ומנין שהקב"ה ירד אליהם שנאמר הבה נרדה ארדה אין כתיב אלא נרדה ומנין מהפיל גורלות בניהם שנאמר בהנחל עליון גוים ונפל גורלו של הקב"ה על אברהם ועל זרעו שנאמר כי חלק יי עמו אמר הקב"ה חבל וגורל זה שנפל עלי רצת נפשי שנאמר חבלי' נפלו לי בנעימי'. וירד הקדוש ברוך הוא ושבעים המלאכים הסובבים כסא כבודו ובלבל את לשונם לשבעים גוים ולשבעים לשון כל אחד ואחד גוי וכתבו ולשונו ומנה מלאך על כל אומה ואומה וישראל נפל בחלקו וחבלו ועל זה נאמ' כי חלק יי' עמו. ומנין שירד הקדוש ברוך הוא שנאמר וירד יי' לראות את העיר ואת המגדל וזו ירידה שנייה והיו רוצין לדבר איש אל רעהו בלשון הקדש ולא מכירין איש לשון רעהו מה עשו לקח איש חרבו ונלחמו אלו עם אלו להשחית וחצי העולם שם נפלו בחרב ומשם הפיצם יי' על פני כל הארץ שנאמר וייפץ יי' אותם משם על פני כל הארץ.

Answer (score 5):

[Daniel 12:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3412.htm) identifies מיכאל‏, Michael:

> ...‏בעת ההיא יעמוד מיכאל שר הגדול העומד על עמך
>
> *And at that time shall Michael stand up, the great prince who standeth for the children of thy people...*

**This is reconciled** with josh waxman's excellent answer by [Exodus Raba Bo 5](http://www.tsel.org/torah/midrashraba/bo.html), that identifies him as the angel that defends us against accusations, rather than an officer appointed over us:

> אמר רבי יוסי למה מיכאל וסמאל<sup>1</sup> דומין לסניגור וקטיגור... 
>    כך מיכאל וסמאל עומדים לפני השכינה והשטן מקטרג ומיכאל
>   מלמד זכותן של ישראל והשטן בא לדבר ומיכאל משתקו‏
>
> *Rabbi Jose said: to what are Michael and Samael<sup>1</sup> compared? To a defender and accuser... So Michael and Samael stand before the Shechina and the Accuser accuses and Michael relates the merits of Israel and the Accuser attempts to speak and Michael silences him.*

[Nachmanides](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/biography/Nachmanides.html) explains further in his commentary on Lev 18:25 along the same lines, that Michael is an officer that seeks out mercy for Israel, not an officer in a sense of overlordship or rule, as is the case with other angels.

---

<sup>1. One should not annunciate this name out loud, nor other names, such as diablo and the like used by other languages, as this is like mentioning the name of a foreign god, (Ex [23:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0223.htm)). Especially at night, (See the book מלאכי עליון‏ by Reuben Margoleous, page רמח‏, footnote עז:א‏)</sup>